# Ad Hoc Reports Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, reporting

I want to allow people to put in simple text search terms, run a pig job (if that's best? it's what I know best) and output the results (the tsv file results?) so I can show them in a web interface.

Is there anything that approaches this problem?
Anything known to link a few disjointed pieces of the flow I am going for, together?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you index the docs into Lucene or Solr?  Then you can do text search in real-time.  Hadoop is designed for batch oriented processes, which doesn't seem like what you want in this case.

Comment: Never done a solr index. I guess proof of concept is the first pass I am going for and implementing a Solr/Lucene index might be more start-up than I am going for.

Comment: Really?  It might be easier to use Solr for a POC than it would be to use Hadoop for something it wasn't designed to do.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on your project's requirements. Does it need low-latency, and how complex is the ad hoc search. Well I think hbase+pig might be a comprised solution. hbase can be used for search real-time search purpose (although its search function is not so powerful than RDBMS) and pig for batch_processing of large amount for data.